# Finding Transformation Matrices Along The Line $y = 2x$

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra

It seems I have fallen behind in my Methods of Theoretical Physics class, and am asking here as I need explanations and resources to learn. Let's say we are given the following:

> "Find the transformation matrix, $N$, which stretches vectors by a factor of 4 along the line $y = 2x$."

How would you go about this? If this just means "the matrix that stretches the y-axis by a factor of 4 and rotates such that $y' = 2x$", then I think I can do that, but would rather the help to be sure.

Comment: Are [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map)  and [also these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) useful? Can you find the matrix with an eigenvector along your line?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Those are definitely useful, though I'm still not sure what the rotation would be in this case. Specifically the part y = 2x confuses me

Comment: Is "4 times the projection operator for $(1,2)^T$" meaningful?

Comment: Find the component of $i$ and $j$ along the line and stretch it by the factor of $4$ and construct a new $i $ and $j $ and that will give you the matrix transformation.

Comment: You could rotate your coordinates to the line ( rotate around Z by 45 degrees), apply a transformation that stretches only in the (new) x direction, then rotate back.

Comment: Vote to close. This question has no physics context. It is pure mathematics and should be on Mathematics SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a basis for the coorinate system.

$e_1 = \begin {bmatrix} 1\\2\end{bmatrix}, e_2=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

That is one vector in the direction of $y=2x$ and one orthogonal.

$B = \begin{bmatrix} 1&-2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$ will transform a vector in our basis to the standard basis.

$B^{-1}$ will then transform a vector in the standard basis to our basis.

$\begin{bmatrix} 4\\&1\end{bmatrix}$ will transform a vector in our basis as desired.

$B\begin{bmatrix} 4\\&1\end{bmatrix}B^{-1}$ will take a vector in the standard basis, transform it to our adjusted frame of reference, dilate in one direction, leaving the other unchanged, and transform back to the standard basis.

$\begin{bmatrix} 1&-2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 4\\&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \frac15&\frac 25\\-\frac25&\frac 15\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}\frac 85&\frac 65\\\frac 65&\frac {17}5\end{bmatrix}$